# Redirect Old Domain to New Domain Except robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, redirect

I'm in the process of moving my old site domain to a new domain. I have all pages redirecting to corresponding pages on the new domain. The old domain's robots.txt file is redirecting to the new domain's robots.txt file. I want to redirect all pages except for the robots.txt file. How would I go about doing this?

My .htaccess file

```
# Redirect the site 
RewriteEngine On 

# Take care of www.olddomain.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ /robots.real [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
# Takes care of olddomain.com 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ /robots.real [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured it out.

Lines 6 and 10 needed to look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ [NC]
```

Which results in this code:

```
# Redirect the site 
RewriteEngine On 

# Take care of www.olddomain.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
# Takes care of olddomain.com 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```